# can't play video in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.widget.MediaController;

// to control media i.e; stop, play, pause

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // start coding from here
        final VideoView buckysVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.buckysVideoView);
        buckysVideoView.setVideoPath("https://www.thenewboston.com/forum/project_files/006_testVideo.mp4");

        // applying mediaControler properties
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(buckysVideoView);
        buckysVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        buckysVideoView.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Explain the question please.it's just code.or add the logcats...

Comment: Where you want to play the video? I don't see full code here.

Comment: Any error? What happens when you try to play?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `setVideoPath` that would be appropriate if the video is stored on your device, you should use `setVideoURI` for video over http.

```
String urlStrinh = "https://www.thenewboston.com/forum/project_files/006_testVideo.mp4";
VideoView buckysVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.buckysVideoView);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(buckysVideoView);
Uri videoURI = Uri.parse(urlString);
buckysVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
buckysVideoView.setVideoURI(videoURI);
buckysVideoView.start();
```